# HTTP Encryption without Authentication

Tags: http, encryption, https, certificate

I want to distribute a small application that offers a web interface intended for local use. It will therefore bind to loopback only, but there is a chance that someone will want to use it on a virtual or real network interface.

At least then, the arising traffic becomes subject to eavesdropping.

I guess I can't burden the user with the job of generating and installing a HTTPS certificate/key, so my question: Is there a way of establishing an encrypted connection with a standard browser without such certificate/key on the server side, abstaining from server authentication?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without SSL and a certificate, you will have to build your own authentication and encryption protocol, which isn't trivial. It's possible to use a self-signed SSL certificate on your web server so that you can use any domain name you want, problem is it requires each client to trust that certificate (by importing it to the machine). In enterprise environment there is also IPSec which protects all traffic.

Answer (score -1):

You can buy a [SSL certificate for a hostname or an IP address](https://www.google.com/search?q=intranet%20ssl) and use it locally.

Comment: After all, then I need to tell him how to disable the warning message from his browser.

Comment: Or you can buy a proper SSL certificate for localhost.

Comment: Since usual machines in a LAN don't have an official DNS address, you can't. The only recipe you can offer is the usual "ignore the warning messages", but with some browsers, you never get rid of those.

Comment: The question specifically asks for solutions other than using a certificate.

Comment: Since when can't one buy a SSL certificate for a LAN server? Example of such offering: http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/ssl/ssl-certificate-intranetssl.html

Comment: @DaleBurrell we are here not only to answer specific questions, but to help finding a feasible solution. SSL certificates for intranet are for real.

Comment: Hm, guess it won't work without corresponding DNS entries; should I deliver a small DNS server with my software? localhost is an exception, but obviously won't work either (unusable name for non-loopback devices).

Comment: I guess most LAN's will have some kind of DNS in present. I would not expose such an interface as the IT dept might not be waiting for another DNS server inside their LAN. Besides, it would take more time to configure the DNS for the clients than to update their own DNS system.